# Styling ag-grid cell based on condition when cell value is changed

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I wanted to apply a css style to a cell, only if the oldValue and newValue are different after the cell is edited. So, I did the below in onCellValueChanged() handler,

```
 onCellValueChanged: function(params) {
    if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
       params.colDef.cellStyle = function(params) {
         return {
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        };
      }
      params.api.redrawRows();
   }
}
```

But this apply the css change to all the cells for that particular column when the condition is met. I am not sure how to apply 'cellStyle' only to the cell affected.

Update 1:
I changed it to below and it started working ,

```
onCellValueChanged: function(params) {
console.log(params);
 var cellValue = params.data[params.colDef.field];
if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
    params.colDef.cellStyle = function(params) {
      if(params.value==cellValue){
        return {
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        };
      }
    }
  params.api.redrawRows();
}
}
```

The problem now I face is that the cell styling (in this case background becoming green) is lost when I edit any other cell under the same column.
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/T6QvkiD7CGhcnB10CI10?p=preview)

Comment: Can you have a look at once to my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691754/angular-ag-grid-attach-class-to-grouped-rows-cell-based-on-validation-of-other-c

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed now, this is the working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iCTFpJ4U5gVAN9r?p=preview)

```
function cellValueChangedListener(params) {
  var oldValue = params.oldValue;
  var newValue = params.newValue;

  var recordKey = params.data.key;
  var columnField = params.colDef.field;

  if (!_.isEqual(oldValue, newValue)) {
    if (!cellMetadata[recordKey]) {
      cellMetadata[recordKey] = {};
  }
  if (!cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField]) {
    cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField] = {};
  }

  cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField].trackChanges = true;
  cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField].tooltip = 
  columnField.toUpperCase() + ' ' + 'Changed from' + ' ' + oldValue + ' ' 
+ 'to' + ' ' + newValue;
  }

  params.api.redrawRows();
}
```